# Get browser window width including scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I tried to get browser window width with `$(window).width();`. On IE 10, it does return the full browser width, include the scroll bar. However, on Firefox and Chrome, both return the value without the scroll bar.

How can I get the browser width include with the scroll bar together? Because I need the detected width to be exactly same as CSS.

Thanks.

Comment: how about $(document).width();

Comment: `I need the detected width to be exactly same as CSS.` Which CSS property are we talking about?

Comment: I don't know what CSS property. But it's Bootstrap responsive CSS.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This will get the full Window's width:

```
 window.outerWidth
```

**NOTE:** jQuery's `outerWidth()` doesn’t work on `$(window)`

Comment: Thanks. But it is still the same. How to detect scrollbar width?

Comment: It is same value as before.

Comment: how about a browser workaround? something like an IE hack for the css. https://gist.github.com/hatefulcrawdad/5068210 <- something like this

Comment: if you have the javascript inspector window to the right of the webpage then `outerWidth` will include the width of the inspector - and as you resize the page itself `outerWidth` won't even change. I think the only purpose of `outerWidth` should be for google analytics type logging of browser window size. It's useless for layout purposes whether you have the inspector window open or not. You probably want `innerWidth` which equates to 'viewport width' for responsive design

Comment: It returns `1920` even though I set the width to 768 on chrome developer tools responsive tool

Comment: this is not good, it includes the whole window, including hte developer toolbar or plugins

Answer (score 79):

The first answer was close, but upon further inspection it is a bit more complicated.  The `body.clientWidth` is the width excluding the scrollbars.  The `window.outerWidth` is the width including the scrollbars and other window elements like the window border.  The `window.innerWidth` is the actual width of the window, including scrollbars, but not including the window border.

[image]

Comment: This should be the correct marked answer, even three years later.

Answer (score 24):

`window.innerWidth` seems to be the correct answer when needed for responsive design

Comment: exactly what I need. As per OP's comment in the question, this should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: This is the answer!

Comment: this is the only correct answer

Answer (score 8):

`window.innerWidth` will give the width of the HTML **and** the scrollbar. This value is the value used for device width breakpoints when using media queries in CSS. Essentially, `window.innerWidth` is equal to the calculated CSS unit `100vw`. However, `window.outerWidth` will give you the width of the entire window.

For example, if you had Chrome's Dev Tools open **inside** of the browser, `window.outerWidth` would be the width of the webpage + scroll bar + Chrome's Dev Tools inspector. While `window.innerWidth` would return the width of just the webpage + scroll bar.