# Padding added to my page when watching Modal, using materialize css classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

Hi im using "Materialize" & flexlider to built my theme,
I have some issue while desktop mode, when watching the modals i created there is some padding from left that added to my site, for now, I'm not sharing the code because I dont know where to start, but, here is a temp' link to the page & image to describe the issue.

*Just click the "Modal!!" button, under the slider. 
Thanks, aviv.

This is my page:
https://optica.000webhostapp.com/

This image describe my issue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's an explicit width being set via the `style` property when the modal is triggered, and it's not taking into account the scrollbar that disappears due to `overflow: hidden`, and so you end up with a width smaller than 100%.

A quick fix would be to either do `body { overflow: auto !important; }`, or `body { width: auto !important; }`, depending on what you intend for it to be (without breaking anything else, of course).

However, the better solution would be to change the behaviour of the modal (if you are able to), and to account for the width including scrollbar with `window.innerWidth` (or see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582862/get-browser-window-width-including-scrollbar)). What modal library are you using?

Comment: Im using Materialize, now I notice that it because i used:

Comment: - i used: body { direction: rtl; } , so that padding that added from left suposed to added from right, and replace the scrollbar that disapear from right in modal mod..