# Find the full width of a page including horizontal scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to find the full width of the page, I have followed lot of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582862/get-browser-window-width-including-scrollbar) on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161304/how-to-reliably-get-screen-width-with-the-scrollbar) but no luck

I have tried

```
$(document).width()
window.outerWidth
window.innerWidth
document.body.scrollWidth
document.body.clientWidth
```

I tried to get these values, in pages with horizontal scroll bar in the bottom and the values I get for all the above code are same 
    console.log($(document).width(),window.outerWidth,window.innerWidth,document.body.scrollWidth,document.body.clientWidth)

> output: 1366 1366 1366 1366 1366

I am trying to find width of old sharepoint pages and they are not properly designed, i.e some tables/images have huge width specified in inline style and they are not contained inside their parent containers

I even tried to find the element with maximum width

var maxwidth = 1300;

```
$("body *").each(function(){
if($(this).width()>maxwidth){
  maxwidth = $(this).width();
}
})
console.log(maxwidth)
```

But it is not reliable. For example, in a page with no scroll bar the maxwidth was `2773` and it was `2000` for a page with scrollbar

Not sure what else can be done for getting the full width of the pages

Comment: What are you expecting? What are you getting instead? Have you done any searching yet (http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/)?

Comment: You mean vertical scrollbar?

Comment: @Abhitalks no the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have added the details now. Please check

Comment: downvoters please drop a comment on what should be improved

Comment: @vignesh: You may go through this - https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/0ychu4hh/ . However, do remember to clean up your question and make it clear. Perhaps the downvotes are because of that. Also, note that horizontal scrollbar is of absolutely no relevance here. What if there is overflow set to hidden?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(this).outerWidth() + $(this).scrollLeft())
  })

})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:100px;width:1600px;background:#b4b4b4"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/kxk5u79n/1/

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var maxWidth = window.innerWidth;

  $('body').children().each(function () {
    var $el = $(this);

    if ($el.width() > maxWidth) {
        $el.css('width', maxWidth);
    }
  });
});
```

Check for the windows width, is an elements width wider we resize it to fit. This may not be fully accurate with margins and paddings.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer from *@Hemant (user:8093451)*, I came up with another solution using Firefox (version 77.0.1 64-Bit):

- Visit desired website and resize browser window to min width
- If the website has an ideal width, a horizontal scrollbar should be visible now
- From the **Firefox Menu** choose **Tools**, **Web Developer**, **Web Console**
- In the bottom left add following javascript code:`console.log(this.outerWidth + this.scrollX)`
- Drag the bar of the horizontal scrollbar to the max right
- Run the javascript code by hitting **Run** or by shortcut Ctrl+Enter (**Web Console** must have focus)
- The wanted value (min width of the website before a horizontal scrollbar appears) should be shown in the **Web Console** output; for example: *1292*.
- Finally, by using a free Firefox add-on like **WindowSizer** (by *Dr. Cheap*) you can set the width of a window to a desired value like *1292*. Besides you can retrieve the current size of a window (not the value from above, but the visible width).

I was looking for a way to set the browser window width to the ideal website width, right before a horizontal scrollbar would be shown. If I remember correctly, this was a feature browsers supported in the past, but seem to lack nowadays. Thanks to your question *@Vignesh Subramanian (user:848841)* I ended up here.